# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

How come I'm getting this error?

My code:

```
def cat_n_times(s, n):
    while s != 0:
        print(n)
        s = s - 1

text = input("What would you like the computer to repeat back to you: ")
num = input("How many times: ")

cat_n_times(num, text)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 82):

1. The reason this is failing is because (Python 3) `input` returns a string. To convert it to an integer, use `int(some_string)`.
2. You do not typically keep track of indices manually in Python. A better way to implement such a function would be

   ```
   def cat_n_times(s, n):
       for i in range(n):
           print(s) 

   text = input("What would you like the computer to repeat back to you: ")
   num = int(input("How many times: ")) # Convert to an int immediately.

   cat_n_times(text, num)
   ```
3. I changed your API above a bit. It seems to me that `n` should be the *number of times* and `s` should be the *string*.

Comment: +1 for using a for-loop. Not just in Python, but in the vast majority of programming languages, the for-loop construct is much better to use than the while-loop construct, because the initialization and update code are kept in closer proximity with the termination condition, reducing the chance of making a mistake.

Comment: it's good to know that only python 2 had the shortcut int(some_string) for int(input(some_string)) in python 3. likewise, raw_input() for returning a string is a python 2 function for input() in python 3.

Answer (score 33):

For future reference Python is [strongly typed](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language). Unlike other dynamic languages, it will not automagically cast objects from one type or the other (say from `str` to `int`) so you must do this yourself. You'll like that in the long-run, trust me!

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, use [annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to prevent such mistakes:

```
def cat_n_times(s: str, n: int):
    for i in range(n):
        print(s)


text = input("What would you like the computer to repeat back to you: ")
num = input("How many times: ")  # Convert to an int immediately.

cat_n_times(text, num)
```

[Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) gives a nice error:

```
annotations.py:9: error: Argument 2 to "cat_n_times" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Annotations **only** do *anything at all* (aside from setting some metadata in relatively obscure places) when combined with a third-party tool like Mypy.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel well, they do also cause ImportErrors etc when done wrong :P
Besides, it's a very sane assumption that people are using IDEs nowadays that usually profit very much from type hints for their integrated checks and hints.