# Unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Thats my code, I don't know why the program gives me that Error.. PD: I'm a beginner in this programming language.

```
import math
while True:
A=input("Escribe el Valor de la 1ra Variable : ")
B=input("Escribe el Valor de la 2da Variable : ") 
C=input("Escribe el Valor de la 3ra Variable : ")
Ec1 = (B * -1)
Ec2 = (B ** 2 - 4 * A * C)
Ec3 = (2*A)
R = math.sqrt(Ec2)
X1 = Ec1 + R / Ec3
X2 = Ec1 - R / Ec3
print('''El Valor de Su Ecuacion Es:/n
X1 = %d
X2 = %d''' % (X1, X2))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 2):

It is failing because `input()` returns a string. To convert it to an integer, you can use `int(some_string)`.

Comment: Good... i Change Input() for int(input()) but when i do that the R give me Other Problem Math Domain Error

Comment: This is probably because you tried to take the square root of a negative number. You need to check if `Ec2` is negative, otherwise `R = math.sqrt(Ec2)` will lead to a math domain error. You will also run into errors if `Ec3` is equal to 0, which will lead to division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting `input("Escribe el Valor de la 1ra Variable : ")`

Put `int(input("Escribe el Valor de la 1ra Variable : ")`

That converts the input to an integer.