# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm am very new to programming and python is my first programming language so please be nice. I have run the following bit of code:

```
searchmovie = raw_input("What movie would you like to rent?\n").lower()
searchindex = dvds.index(searchmovie)
r = csv.reader(open('dvd_info.csv'))
lines = [l for l in r]
currentvalue = lines[searchindex][2]
lines[searchindex][2] = currentvalue - 1
writer = csv.writer(open('tmp.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerows(lines)
```

and I've gotton the error:

```
    lines[searchindex][2] = currentvalue - 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `currentvalue` is a string, you need to convert it to `int` first.

Comment: Do `lines[searchindex][2] = str(int(currentvalue) - 1)`

Comment: Thank you so so much! Aha sorry it was a very amateur question.

Comment: Thank you both for your help :)

Comment: @AKS can you submit your comment as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `currentvalue` is a string, you need to convert it to `int` first:

```
lines[searchindex][2] = str(int(currentvalue) - 1)
```

This code is extracted from @ozgur's comment.