# How to fix "unsupported operand type(s)" in Python?

Tags: python, runtime-error

```
total=0
output=("enter next sales value")
sales=input
total_sales=total+sales
```

I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 4, in  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: it is `sales=input()` or you define sales as a function.

Comment: i did that but then again this error came...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please learn how to read error messages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int

Comment: i still dont get it

Answer (score 1):

You must use input() instead of input.
Moreover in python 3, the input() function returns a string, not an integer. So to use the return value in an addition, you must indicate it as an integer:

```
    sales = input("Enter next sales value")
    total_sales = total + int(sales)
```

Comment: you don't answer the question. AND that's only true with python 3.

Comment: and again ....Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'print("hi")'

Comment: Do you use python 2 or 3 ? What do you enter as input ?