# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in python, but the code below keep returning:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

instead of returning the total sum of the price for all fruit on the list parsed into the function call

Code:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for number in food:
        total += number
    return total

compute_bill(['apple'])
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello Kasramvd. Even when i called the function like print compute_bill(food)  the error message wont stop popping up.

Comment: Can we see how you called `compute_bill`?

Comment: Well, what do you expect the result of `0 + 'apple'` to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is trying to add the string name of the food to the total. Try this:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for f in food:
        number = prices.get(f, 0)
        total += number
    return total
```

The `.get()` will solve the problem of passing in a food that does not have an entry in the `prices` dict: if e.g., `"apple"` does not have a price, it will simply add `0` to the total. This will make it so your program will not crash if you do: `commute_bill(['appple', 'grape'])`. That is, it will not crash if you try to compute the price of a misspelled fruit, or a fruit that is not in `prices`. However, it may be desirable for your program to crash (or at least raise an error when bad data is entered, and handle that error) - that part is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for number in food:
        total += prices[number]  # You need to pull from the prices dictionary
    return total
```

This doesn't solve the issue of having no `"apples"` in inventory though.