# Python 3 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
#Import the module
from math import sqrt

#Using while loop statement to make the program not finish before the user close the program.
while True:

#Print out the introduction message, and get the input value to solve the quadratic equation.
    print("ax^2+bx+c=0의 꼴로 된 방정식을 풀 수 있습니다. a, b, c의 값을 차례대로 입력하세요.")
    a = input("a를 입력하세요 : ")
    b = input("b를 입력하세요 : ")
    c = input("c를 입력하세요 : ")

#Define function that checks whether the input values are natural number or negative number
    def func_num(n):
        if n[0] == '-':
            n = -int(n[1:])
        else:
            n = int(n)

#Execute the function for the input value a, b, c
    func_num(a); func_num(b); func_num(c);

#This if statement chekcs whether the solution of the quadratic equation going to be real number or imaginary number.
    if b ** 2 < 4*a*c:
        solution1 = ((sqrt((b ** 2)-(4*a*c)))-b) / (2*a)
        solution2 = (-(sqrt((b ** 2)-(4*a*c)))-b) / (2*a)
    else:
        square_root = sqrt( -(b**2 - 4*a*c) ) + 1j
        solution1 = ( (square_root)  - b  ) / (2*a)
        solution2 = ( -(square_root)  - b  ) / (2*a)

#Prints out the solution of the quadratic equation.
    print("정답은 바로바로... {}, {} 이거다!".format(solution1, solution2))
```

but it gives an error (for any input a, b, c that are integer):

```
Python 3 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

I think the problem is related to func_num() (because that error occurs when I do the calculation with number and strings)

But I still can't find which part is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: Your argument is a `str` because you aren't parsing it. Have a look at how to parse input into numeric types.

Comment: @DJV But I did use int() to convert it into integer (in the if statement)

Comment: Your calls to ``func_num()`` convert the user-typed strings into ints - and then throw them away.  You would need to actually return the converted values, and assign them back to your a,b,c variables.

Comment: @jasonharper I used `n = -int(n[1:])` and `n = int(n)` to assign new value to variable n. Is this code wrong? If so, why is it wrong?

Comment: The ``n`` in the function is a local variable, assigning to it has NO outside effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason giving u type error is you did not store and update the variables after calling the function.

Try

```
 a = func_num(a)
 b = func_num(b)
 c = func_num(c)
```

And modify your function to return n because you only passing a copy n into the function

Comment: I changed it to `a = func_num(a); b = func_num(b); c = func_num(c);` but it still doesn't work. gives same error.

Comment: and return n at the end of the function!

Comment: Thank you, it works well :) But why should I use `return n` to make it work properly?

Comment: @장은수 It is because when u call the function it is only passing a copy and it is totally irrelevant to the values in the main. And when u update the value in main, the function must return a value so that u can assign that value to the variable :)