# Python Square Root Calculator Error

Tags: python, calculator, square-root, calculation

I wanted to make a simple square root calculator.

```
num = input('Enter a number and hit enter: ')

if len(num) > 0 and num.isdigit():
    new = (num**0.5)
    print(new)
else:
    print('You did not enter a valid number.')
```

It doesn't seem as if I have done anything wrong, however, when I attempt to run the program and after I have input a number, I am confronted with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/username/Documents/Coding/squareroot.py", line 4, in <module>
new = (num**0.5)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You carefully check if the input *could* be converted to a number, then *don't actually bother to do that*!

Comment: Also, numbers like `1.5` or `1E10` will not be valid - why? The pythonic way would be to `try` converting the input to a `float` and to print the error message only when an exception occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solution. Here try and catch is capable of handling all kinds of input. So your program will never fail. And since the input is being converted to float. You won't face any type related error.

```
try:
    num = float(input('Enter a positive number and hit enter: '))
    if num >= 0:
        new = (num**0.5)
    print(new)

except:
    print('You did not enter a valid number.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Input function returns you string value. so you need to parse it properly

```
num = raw_input('Enter a number and hit enter: ')

if num.isdigit():
  if int(num) > 0:
      new = (int(num)**0.5)
      print(new)
else:
    print('You did not enter a valid number.')
```

Comment: Then, his second line will fail.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it ruled out that error. However, I am now give another error message: 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/username/Documents/Coding/squareroot.py", line 3, in <module>
    if len(num) > 0 and num.isdigit():
    TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi What is the difference between my answer and yours?

Comment: @eyllanesc I just did parsing in first attempt and encounter isdigit problem. You can see the difference. I have executed and then updated my code.

Comment: In the original question, that task is already in place, I do not put it for that. I still see you copied my answer.

Comment: Ah, updated my code again after that edit. It works fine now, I really appreciate your help. 

This is my first stackoverflow post and my question got answered much faster than I thought it would. As in, in less than 1 minute.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @eyllanesc Does it require to copy your answer for such small things? Buddy I didn't looked at your answer. As soon as I saw Lucas comment on my answer I tried to run and check. Anyway I am here to learn from other.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math module for simple calculations.
refer: [Math module Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)

```
import math
num = raw_input('Enter a number and hit enter: ')

if num.isdigit():
    num = float(num)
    new = math.sqrt(num)
    print(new)
else:
    print('You did not enter a valid number.')
```