# Homework Help: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python

Having much trouble figuring out what I have done wrong. I am a student in a intro python course. The prof does not explain things very well.

We are trying to compute the angles of a triangle. He wants us to use .split so we can enter the values all at once. And go from there. I think that is where my problem might lie. Here is my code.

```
import math
user_input = (input('Enter three points: '))

numbers = user_input.split(',')

x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 = numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], 
numbers[4], numbers[5]

a = math.sqrt((x2 - x3) * (x2 - x3) + (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3))
b = math.sqrt((x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y2 - y3))
c = math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 + x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2))

A = math.degrees(math.acos((a * a - b * b - c * c) / (-2 * b * c)))
B = math.degrees(math.acos((b * b - a * a - c * c) / (-2 * a * c)))
C = math.degrees(math.acos((c * c - b * b - a * a) / (-2 * a * b)))

print("The three angles are ", round(A * 100) / 100.0,
  round(B * 100) / 100.0, round(C * 100) / 100.0)
```

And when I try to enter values for my triangle I get this error. I am quite new, so I am not sure exactly how to fix this.

```
Enter three points: 1, 1, 6.5, 1, 6.5, 2.5
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\smwht\Desktop\Python Stuff\ComputeAngles.py", line 12, in <module>
>       a = math.sqrt((x2 - x3) * (x2 - x3) + (y2 - y3) * (y2 - y3))
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: `numbers` is a list of strings... you need to convert them to `int` or `float`: `numbers = map(float, user_input.split(','))`. The `map()` call applies `float()` to each member of the list, generating a list of floats.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 2):

Because you try to use string for arithmetic operator. This will help

```
numbers = [float(i) for i in user_input.split(',')]
```

Wrong Code maybe

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input().split()` you get a list of strings, so you should convert it to floats, heres an example using list comprehension:

```
numbers = [float(x) for x in user_input.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string, `split()` returns an array of strings, you can use `float()` to convert them to numbers:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 = float(numbers[0]), float(numbers[1]), float(numbers[2]), float(numbers[3]), float(numbers[4]), float(numbers[5])
```

Or for less code:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 = map(float, numbers)
```

Even less:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 = map(float, input('Enter three points: ').split(','))
```

Comment: This is what I get when I use your fix. What is the deal now?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\smwht\Desktop\Python Stuff\ComputeAngles.py", line 14, in <module>
    c = math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 + x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2))
ValueError: math domain error

Comment: Because the evaluated number inside `math.sqrt(...)` is negative. What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Never mind! It was because inside one of my () I had a + and in the other I had a -. My bad. My program works now! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A spiffed-up version with lots of comments:

```
# you can import just the functions you want, and
#   call them directly like sqrt() instead of math.sqrt()
from math import acos, degrees, sqrt

# functions make it easy to reuse, document and test bits of code

def get_floats(prompt, sep=None):
    # A docstring - if you type "help(get_floats)" it will display this.
    """
    Prompt until one or more numbers are entered
    """
    nums = []
    while not nums:  # repeat until nums is not empty
        string = input(prompt)
        try:
            # a list comprehension - do something to each item in a list,
            #   and return the results as another list.
            # In this case, each piece of the split string gets converted to float()
            nums = [float(s) for s in string.split(sep)]
        except ValueError:
            # exceptions help you to handle unexpected problems,
            #   like if someone tries to enter 'banana' when asked for a number
            pass
    return nums

def dist(p1, p2):
    """
    Return Cartesian distance between two points
    """
    # zip() is a very useful function for combining several lists in parallel -
    #   if you call zip(list1, list2, list3) it will give you the first
    #   item from each list, then the second item from each, etc.
    # In this case, we treat each point as a list of coordinates - [x1, y1, z1]
    #   and when we zip two points we get the coordinates in each dimension:
    #   zip([x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2])  ->  [[x1, x2], [y1, y2], [z1, z2]]
    #
    # The loop,  (b - a) ** 2 for a, b in zip(p1, p2)
    #   is a generator expression - it's like a list comprehension,
    #   but it yields a value at a time instead of a whole list at once.
    #   It is sometimes a little bit slower, but takes less memory.
    # 
    # For each pair of coordinates we square the difference -
    #   then we sum all of the squares and take the root,
    #   which gives us Cartesian distance.
    #
    # The neat thing is, this loop doesn't care how many dimensions you give it -
    #   it will work on 2d points, or 3d, or 5d. If you give it a pair
    #   of 27-dimensional points, it will happily return the distance
    #   in 27-dimensional space.
    return sqrt(sum((b - a) ** 2 for a, b in zip(p1, p2)))

def get_angle(a, b, c, use_degrees=True):
    """
    Given the lengths of three sides of a triangle,
      return the angle opposite side c
    """
    # using cosine law
    angle = acos((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a * b))
    if use_degrees:
        angle = degrees(angle)
    return angle

def main():
    # get points of a triangle
    p1 = get_floats("Enter point 1: ", ",")
    p2 = get_floats("Enter point 2: ", ",")
    p3 = get_floats("Enter point 3: ", ",")

    # get side lengths
    a = dist(p2, p3)
    b = dist(p1, p3)
    c = dist(p1, p2)

    # get angles
    A = get_angle(b, c, a)
    B = get_angle(a, c, b)
    C = get_angle(a, b, c)

    # show results using string formatting (automatically rounds the result)
    print(
        "The three angles are {:0.2f}, {:0.2f} and {:0.2f}"
        .format(A, B, C)
    )

main()
```