# Problems with making a day converter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm a fairly new python coder, so any help would be great. I want my code to do something like this:

```
How many days? 600
600 days is equivalent to 85.71428571428571 weeks.
600 days is equivalent to 20.0 months.
600 days is equivalent to 1.64385616438356 years.
```

But when I try to play my code:

```
x = input("How many days?")
w = 7
m = 30
y = 365
print(f"{x} days is equivalent to {x/w} weeks.")
```

It says something like this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: x is type string and you cannot calculate with strings

Comment: You have 3 parentheses at the end of `print` which should only be 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division need's `int`, so:

```
import sys
x = input("How many days?")
if x.isdigit():
    x=int(x)
else:
    print('non-numeric day')
    sys.exit()
...
```

It's python 3 not python 2 anymore, so `input` from python 2 is removed and `raw_input` is renamed to `input`

Btw at the end:

```
print(f"{x} days is equivalent to {x/w} weeks.")
```

Comment: What happens if a user types a letter instead of a number?

Comment: @PedroLobito Edited mine

Answer (score 2):

The `input` function *always* returns a string in Python 3, so you'll have to write:

```
x = int(input('How many days? '))
```

At the moment, you're trying to perform...

```
str / int
# and you need 
int / int
```

So casting the result of input to int will work as long as the input *can* be converted. You could delve into functions and error handling if you like to ensure a proper input is entered:

```
def int_input(prompt):
  while True:
    try:
      x = int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
      print('bad input!')
    else:
      return x
```

And then replace your `int(input(...))` with `int_input(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the 'x' variable is read from the input as a string. Try converting it to an int

So do this:

```
try:
    x = int(input("How many days?"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)
w = 7
m = 30
y = 365
print(f"{x} days is equivalent to {x/w} weeks.")
```

note, that I am doing a try here, since if the user provides non-numeric values, there will be an error (as it should). Consider a better way of accounting this.

Comment: Assuming that you have `from sys import exit`?

Comment: Import is not needed, but it is recommended to use ‘sys.exit’ in production instead of ‘exit’, which is intended for use from interactive python session.