# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -:

Tags: python-3.x, string, int

"I am totally new to programming". I installed dynasor software, and when I ran it, faced with some problems. i tried to solve them, but i don't know how to solve the below problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dynasor", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('dynasor==0.1.2', 'dynasor')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1462, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dynasor-0.1.2-py3.5-cygwin-3.0.7-i686.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/dynasor", line 536, in <module>
    fn and writer(fn, output)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dynasor-0.1.2-py3.5-cygwin-3.0.7-i686.egg/dsf/output.py", line 39, in create_mfile
    fh.write("\n%% %s\n%s = ...\n%s;\n" % (desc, n, str(v)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 1463, in array_str
    return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 623, in array2string
    options['linewidth'] -= len(suffix)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

here "[TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)" I found a solution, but it does not work for me.
for example, when I put `len(int(suffix))` in "arrayprint.py", line 623, i face with another error:

`options['linewidth'] -= len(int(suffix))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

or when I put int(len(suffix)), it gives this error:

`options['linewidth'] -= int(len(suffix))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'`

I installed dynasor in this way "pip3.5 install dynasor", and also numpy in this way "pip3.5 install numpy==1.14.1".

Answer (score 0):

## Answer:

At the end of your traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 623, in array2string
    options['linewidth'] -= len(suffix)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int
```

This means that you're trying to substract a **string** with an **int**, which is impossible.
The function `len(...)` always gives you an **int**, so it seems that `options['linewidth']` is a **string**.
I recommend that wherever you set the value of `options['linewidth']` in your code you first transform this value with `int(...)`.
If `options['linewidth']` comes from a library and you can't change the code that set its value, you can still do `options['linewidth'] = int(options['linewidth'])` before using it.

## Side note:

You need to understand that every variable has a type, and every type has restricted operations that you can do on them:
-> The `int(...)` function will try to convert what you give it to an **int**, if you give it a **float** (decimal number) it will take off the decimal part, if you give it a **string** that represents an **int**, like `'-42'`, it will try to convert it to an int, but if you give it a string that can't be interpreted as an int, such as `'dog'` it will raise the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dog'`
-> Using `len(...)` on a **string** will always give you the size of the string as an **int**, so using `int(len(...))` is redundant.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you mean i substitute each "options['linewidth']" with "int(options['linewidth'])", if yes, i did it, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: no you can't do that, instead you can do `options['linewidth'] = int(options['linewidth'])` before doing anything with `options['linewidth']`

Comment: previous problems that i solved them were about "Python map object is not subscriptable", and i replaced each `map()` with `list(map())`, but it was in another file ( i mean a file with name of "dynasor"). and above error is in the file of "arrayprint.py".  do you think there is relation between these two matters.

Comment: I don't see any relation between these. `list(...)` can transform anything to a list, but in your case the error comes from a substraction between a string and an int