# How do I append the user input (integer) with a string in python?

Tags: python, append

```
rep_number = int(input('X time(s)'))

ther_note.append(+ rep_number + "time(s).")
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: Also consider using string interpolation: `print(f"{rep_number} time(s).")`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append a string and an integer as one element so I think the easiest way would be to cast the integer into a string with `str(rep_number)`. You can also use`format()` to generate the whole thing as a string with `("{0} times").format(rep_num)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in your example, but there are ways. If you're just getting the input to print out and won't be using it as an actual integer you can just append the formatted string using an `f-string`

```
ther_note = []
rep_number = int(input('X time(s)'))
ther_note.append(f"{rep_number} times(s)")
```

If you need to use the number later on, store the numbers and add the text later on when you need it.

```
ther_note = []
rep_number = int(input('X time(s)'))
ther_note.append(rep_number)

for x in ther_note:
    print(f"{x + 100} times(s)")
```

Other ways to add `ints` and `strs`:

```
num = 10
sentence = "My age is "
print(sentence + str(num))
```

Or

```
num = 10
sentence = "My age is {}".format(num)
print(sentence)
```