# why does input('str' + int ) work and print(int + 'str') doesnot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-2.x

Why does `input('str' + int )` work and `print(int + 'str')` does not?

I used:

```
x = ("enter " + t + "th value")      ''' here type(t) = int '''
```

and it worked, but I used `print (230 + "k $")` and it is showing

```
Type-error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Why did the former line of code work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError

Comment: I contest your assertion that `"enter " + t` works if `t` really has type `int`.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Python? You cannot add strings and numbers—in neither order—in Python. This does work e.g. in JavaScript though.

Comment: @poke I am pretty sure this is Python because of the error message: `Type-error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' `

Answer (score -1):

The main difference here is whether or not the `+` operator is well-defined for that data type. If we consider the `str` type, it makes sense that we would implement addition for strings such that adding some other data type would have the effect of appending it as a string. To show what the overly-simplified code for this might look like, we could say

```py
class str:
    def __add__(self, num: int) -> str:
        return self + str(num)
```

which makes sense. Now, if we consider what addition might look like for an integer, it makes far less sense to think about adding a string. Numerically, if we have the number `5`, and then your math teacher said "okay class, now add the word 'foobar' to the number 5", you would have no idea what to do. This is essentially the idea behind overloading operators in a programming language; in fact, the problem you stated right here is one of the most common complaints with the Javascript language, because people don't consider the logic behind implementing arithmetic operators for different data types.

edit: it has been pointed out to me that python doesn't even allow adding `int`s to `str`s, so my point falls a bit flat for python; however, I hope the notion sticks for object-oriented languages in general.

Comment: While your explanation makes sense, Python doesn’t have such a method that allows concatenating strings and ints; and Python also doesn’t allow method overloading, especially not by type, so this example won’t work in Python.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I will admit I am far less familiar with python than I am with C/C++ and other object-oriented languages, so that's my fault for not researching a bit. However, hopefully this helps him understand the logic behind certain operators making sense for some data types rather than for others.