# Unable to accept user-input and use it without errors

Tags: python-3.x, variables, type-conversion, user-input

Ok, I've been on this for a few days and not able to fix it myself.

Python 3 and working on this snippet of code below. My problem is with variable types and the user-input. This code is part of a larger code I'm wanting a user (me mostly) to be able to use meaningful variable names ("m_earth" for earth mass, and similar quantities) as input for the calculation for "F1", and for others I'd like to use....IF...I can get this part working first.

I have tried using "float" and "int" and it really just creates other errors that I can't fix.

Below the code included is what happens when this code is used.

Anyone have some suggestions...please?

Thanks

```
G = float(6.674E-11)

# All masses are in Kg
m_earth = 5.972E24
m_moon = 7.345E22

m1 = input('Enter the first mass  ')
print(m1, 'Kg')

m2 = input('Enter the second mass  ')
print(m2, 'Kg')

r = input('Enter the center-to-center distance from mass m1 to mass m2  ')

F1 = G * m1 * m2 / r ** 2
print('The gravitational force is  ', F1, "N")
```

---

```
Enter the first mass  m_earth
m_earth Kg
Enter the second mass  m_moon
m_moon Kg
Enter the center-to-center distance from mass m1 to mass m2  3E12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/My Python Programs/try it.py", line 15, in <module>
    F1 = G * m_earth * m_moon / r ** 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: A quick fix would be to add the `m1 = eval(m1)` and `m2=eval(m2)` lines before the F1 calcul. It works and it's fine as long as you are the only user and you know which variables you already defined

Comment: `input()` returns a string which you cannot multiply, add, etc.. with an `int` or `float`.

Comment: Thanks....I added it according to the following --- r = input('Enter the center-to-center distance from mass m1 to mass m2  ')
m1 = eval(m1)
m2 = eval(m2)

F1 = G * m_earth * m_moon / r ** 2 --------- and I get the following error:    " F1 = G * m_earth * m_moon / r ** 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int' "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376520/12479639 Here is one of the many answers that will give you an idea of how to fix it.

Comment: Just an aside, NEVER use `eval` on unchecked user input if you expect that other people will use your program. It can be extremely dangerous.

Comment: Luka --- Sorry, yes that worked, but I needed to include "r" in that too I guess.

Comment: Axw319.....thanks for the heads-up. I don't understand what it fixes, or why it's not a good idea, but I'm gonna see what other ideas come along. I may have to wait for a more robust answer....and then I need to make sure I understand it.....I try to make all efforts on my own before asking questions.....so I learn things, so I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Axe319 Yeah I know, that's why I said its a quick fix if they want to move on and know for sure only they will be using the program. Fiz, glad it could help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: Axe319 --- on the string, int and float....yes, that's what I'm running into, I've tried using all of them in combinations (because I don't really know what I'm doing much yet or why). Hoping someone has a fix for this.....

Comment: @fiz The linked question _tells you the fix_. Please read and understand that question and its answers.

Comment: Axe319 ---- No, that didn't help, but thanks. I tried int(), float(), etc and all it does is create a new error.

Comment: @fiz `m1 = float(input('Enter the first mass  '))` and `m2 = float(input('Enter the second mass  '))` as well as a `float()` around your `r` input will make your program function. However, you will benefit a lot more from understanding WHY it makes it function than just blindly putting it in your code.

Comment: That is assuming the person entering is always entering numbers.

Comment: Pranav Hosangadi --- missed replying to you, sorry. I'm not that good at coding yet, and I don't see/understand how that helps. I've tried using int() and it seems to just create another error that I can't fix.

Comment: Axe319 --- using 'float' just causes this: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'm_earth'

Comment: @fiz I added an answer. If you need any clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `input()` always returns a string.
The reason you cannot add arbitrary strings to `int`s or `float`s is because in most cases it does not make sense.

Consider `3 + 'Hello'`.
What would you expect the outcome to be?

So how do we take care of this? We convert it to something python understands as being allowed to perform arithmetic functions on. In python those types are `int`(whole numbers) and `float` fractional numbers. For arguments sake, there are many others but you don't need them for your example.

Since we cannot guarantee that the user has entered a number, we need some type of check to make sure they did.

That is where we can use a `try`/`except` block.

```
G = float(6.674E-11)

# All masses are in Kg
m_earth = 5.972E24
m_moon = 7.345E22

m1 = input('Enter the first mass  ')
print(m1, 'Kg')

m2 = input('Enter the second mass  ')
print(m2, 'Kg')

r = input('Enter the center-to-center distance from mass m1 to mass m2  ')

# any Error that occurs in the try block
# will hand control to the except block
# if the type of Exception in except is 
# the type of error that occurred
try:
    # here we try to convert the variable m1 of type str
    # to a variable of type float
    # since float() "returns" a float and does not convert in place
    # we need to catch the output it gives into the same variable
    m1 = float(m1)
    m2 = float(m2)
    r = float(r)
    F1 = G * m1 * m2 / r ** 2
    print('The gravitational force is  ', F1, "N")
# any conversion error here will result in a ValueError
# We can catch that specific error and alert the user they 
# mis-entered some data
except ValueError as v:
    print('Some of your input is not valid.')
```

But you wanted be able to specify the name of the variable.
For that you can use a python `dict`. A `dict` maps a key to some value.
Keys can be a number of types, but most importantly, they can be a str, the type that `input()` returns.
In this case it could be `m_earth`.

```
# we need sys to do an early exit in the program
# if the data entered is not a key in the dict
import sys

G = float(6.674E-11)

# All masses are in Kg
my_dict = {'m_earth': 5.972E24,
           'm_moon': 7.345E22}

m1 = input('Enter the first mass  ')
# this will raise a KeyError
# if the key is not in your dict
try:
    m1 = my_dict[m1]
except KeyError as k:
    sys.exit('That name is invalid.')
print(m1, 'Kg')

m2 = input('Enter the second mass  ')
try:
    m2 = my_dict[m2]
except KeyError as k:
    sys.exit('That name is invalid.')

r = input('Enter the center-to-center distance from mass m1 to mass m2  ')

try:
    r = float(r)
    F1 = G * m1 * m2 / r ** 2
    print('The gravitational force is  ', F1, "N")
except ValueError as v:
    print('Some of your input is not valid.')
```

Comment: Axe319 ---- well, that works, and I appreciate all the work you put in. I knew about the string stuff from the 'input', and my attempts around it using int and float just wasn't the way to go, and I'm not good enough to get past that catch-22 (as I saw it). I don't understand WHY your code works, but I'll have to spend time with it and hope I can adapt this to the rest of my code for this project, and understand why it works and why it fixes this problem I had. Thanks again  (thumbs-up)

Comment: @fiz Just to point you in the right direction, look up python `dict`s and how they function. I believe that is the part you're missing.