# numpy: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^=: 'str' and 'int' python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes

I am trying to practice AES encryption on Python.

I have a function in my code called (addRoundKey)

```
def addRoundKey(state, roundKey):
    for i in range(16):
        state[i] ^= roundKey[I]
```

it basically suppose  to XOR state with round key but I am getting this error:

```
state[i] ^= roundKey[i]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^=: 'str' and 'int'
```

I am using numpy module to create state [ ] array

```
from numpy.distutils.system_info import tmp
from numpy.random._examples.cffi.extending import state

def keyExpansionCore(x, i):

def subBytes(state):


def shiftRows(state):


def mixColumns():



def addRoundKey(state, roundKey):
 for i in range(16):
    state[i] ^= roundKey[i]



def encrypt(message, key):
  for i in range(16):
    state[i] = message[i]

numberOfRounds = 1
keyExpansion()
addRoundKey(state, key)
  for round in range(numberOfRounds):
    subBytes(state)
    shiftRows(state)
    mixColumns()
    addRoundKey(state, key)
# Final round
subBytes(state)
shiftRows(state)
addRoundKey(state, key)



def main():
 message = input("Enter a message: ")
 key = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
 encrypt(message, key)


if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Comment: Ok, so do you understand what the error message is telling you? It's telling you that you are trying to use `^` with a `str` and `int`, in this case, `state[i]` is a string

Comment: thanks for reply, yes I know what it means but my question is how to change array [ ] to int. or how to specify the type of the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int