# Loopy to python, starter level

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python by myself, by turing simple maths problems into python codes. I got stuck with a simple loopy, which was as following:
a3 = (1+a2)/a1.

The exercice continues then as a4 = (1+a3)/a2 ect...
I managed to enter the input fonction, but it seems like there is a problem later in the code, as python sends back "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'".

Would you mind giving me a tipp to finish it?! Here is my code (with a1 = x; a2 = y; a3 = w):

```
        w = 1.

        print('give me a number:')

        x = input()

        print('give me a number:')

        y = input()

        w = (int((1+y)/x))

        print (int(type(w)))
```

Thank you very much. I know it is very basic, but we all started by those easy mistakes, didn't we ?! (I am trying to convince my brain that I am not too stupid...:) Thank you

Comment: The `input` function gives you a string (type `str`). You have to convert to int: `x = int(input())`.

Comment: `w = (int((1+y)/x))` the problem is there you divide and integer with a string. replace it with `w = int((1+y)/int(x))` and it will work.Or better change the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your input to a number in order to use it in math. You do so for example with `int(string)` or `float(string)` functions. This is required because the input function returns a string.
I am not sure if I get it right, but this is what I come up with your description:

```py
a1 = float(input("enter a number, hit ctrl+c to exit: "))
a2 = float(input("enter a number, hit ctrl+c to exit: "))

while True:
  a3 = (1 + a2) / a1
  a1 = a2
  a2 = a3

  print("a3: %f" % a3)
```

You have to hit ctrl+c to exit the loop. Output:

```py
enter a number, hit ctrl+c to exit: 1234
enter a number, hit ctrl+c to exit: 9876
...
a3: 1234.000000
a3: 9876.000000
a3: 8.004052
a3: 0.000912
a3: 0.125051
a3: 1234.000000
a3: 9876.000000
a3: 8.004052
^Ca3: 0.000912
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/booboo/loopy.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("a3: %f" % a3)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Nice, you could upvote this so others can see it as a working answer to your question.