# [ Sub function ]TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python

I am using Python 3 but got this error below when using DataFrame.sub() function:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

The dataframe 1 is 4000 rows * 1755 columns **with missing value** and the dataframe 2 is 4000 rows * 1 columns. But as I know, DataFrame.sub() function will give missing value NaN and can still calculate.

However, when I reduced to both dataframes' row number to 5 (without any missing value) and run sub function. It works.

Thanks to all of you answering this question.

dataframe 1:

[image]

dataframe 2:

[image]

Original Codes:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date, format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
df1 = df1.set_index(["date"])
print(df1.tail())

df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date, format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
df2 = df2.set_index(["date"])
print(df2.tail())

df_df1 = df1.sub(df2.RF, axis = 0)
df_df1.tail()
```

Comment: Are we supposed to just guess what the code looks like?

Comment: Check columns type. `df1.info()` & `df2.info()`. Maybe one of your columns has str type.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I've added the code in the end.

Comment: @Corralien

df1.info(): dtypes: float64(1753), object(2) vs. df2.info(): dtypes: float64(1) are because df1's 2 objects cause this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Yes this is the reason of your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)