# Calculating length of side of the triangle

Tags: python, math

Hi I have problem that says:

```
PS C:\Users\root\Documents\lpthw> python .\ex3.1.py
Podaj długość: 5
Który bok: przypdl, przypkr, przec: przec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\Documents\lpthw\ex3.1.py", line 22, in <module>
    find(dl)
  File "C:\Users\root\Documents\lpthw\ex3.1.py", line 13, in find
    przypkr=x/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

My code:

```
import math
a=0
b=0
x=0
c="abc"
przypdl=0
przypkr=0
przec=0
dl=input("Podaj długość: ")
def find(x):
    c=input("Który bok: przypdl, przypkr, przec: ")
    if c=="przec":
        przypkr=x/2
        przypdl=przypkr*math.sqrt(3)
    elif c=="przypkr":
        przypdl=x*math.sqrt(3)
        przec=x*2
    else:
        przypkr=x/math.sqrt(3)
        przec=przypkr*2
    print(f'przeciwprostokątna: {przec}, krótsza przyprostokątna: {przypkr}, dłuższa przyprostokątna: {przypdl}')
find(dl)
```

**Im starting with coding so that will be realy helpfull, thanks!**
The purpose of my code is calculating length of side of the triangle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: Try `dl=int(input("Podaj długość: "))`

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input you are getting is a string. You have to convert it to an int first.

```
dl=int(input("Podaj długość: "))
```

You also have to make przypkr, przec, and przypdl global because you are referencing those variables in a function. Adding these three lines in the beginning of the function should fix that.

```
global przypkr
global przec
global przypdl
```